# A person who is super excited for something

Tags: american-english

What do we call a person who is super excited for something?

Comment: Can you provide a sentence where you intend to use the word ?  Excited by  what ?

Comment: We call him a "super-excited person".

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92175/can-zealot-have-a-positive-connotation?s=1|1.7694 and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202304/are-there-big-difference-in-the-degree-of-zeal-among-fan-enthusiast-maniac-f?s=2|0.5367

Answer (score 2):

*[Fanatic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fanatic?q=Fanatic)*:

> noun
>
> 1 A person filled with excessive and single-minded zeal, especially
>   for an extreme religious or political cause:

*He paints his face black and gold because he's a **fanatic** about the Pittsburgh Steelers.*

Comment: Usually in everyday conversation it's shortened to "fan", and used with the preposition "of". As in "He paints his face black and gold because he's a fan of the Pittsburgh Steelers." The full word (fanatic) has a negative context (e.g. "religious fanatic").

Answer (score 2):

Rabid

Zealous

Fervent

Energetic

Exhilarated

Answer (score 0):

It depends what he's excited about.

- If the thing he is excited about is participating in an ongoing or upcoming activity, the most apt term is **gung ho** (or **gung-ho**).
- If the object of his excitement is a person whom he idolizes or enamored of  (eg a female pop singer) you might say he is **star-struck** or **{gaga/crazy} {over/for} her**
- If he is excited sexually (aroused) there are many slang terms, some quite vulgar . Some printable ones: **hot to trot** (old fashioned) or just **hot [for her]** (newer—see, for instance, https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Xrx_55SgwAY )